# Javascript loop + MVC foreach

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, for-loop

I'm building an restaurantfinder in EPiServer MVC and I've encountered some problem. I'm looping through my searchresults in my view, and for each result, I create a div with some information. I also want to create markers on my google map for every div created, tho I can't get it to work. It's like there's only 1 teaserdiv when I can see 3-4 on my page.

View:

```
   <div class="row">
        @foreach (var res in Model.RestaurantResults)
        {
            <div class="hidden">
                <p id="long">@res.Longitude</p>
                <p id="lat">@res.Latitude</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-11 pull-right">
                <ul id="destinations">
                    <li style="list-style-type: none">
                        <div class="teaser">
                            <span class="h2"><a href="@UrlResolver.Current.GetUrl(res.LinkURL)">@res.HeadLine</a></span>
                            <br/>
                            <span class="h4" id="address">@res.Adress</span><br/>
                            <span class="h5">@res.Phone</span>
                            <p>@res.TeaserText</p>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        }
</div>
```

JS:

```
    var res = [document.getElementById(".teaser")];
    function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            center: { lat: document.getElementById("lat"), lng: document.getElementById("long") },
            zoom: 13
        });
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

        var address = document.getElementById('address').innerHTML;
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: "<h5>" + address + "</h5>"
        });
        geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function(results, status) {
            if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                 for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++)  {
                    createMarker(results[i]);
                }
            }
        });
    }


function createMarker(place) {
    var marker = new window.google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: place.geometry.location,
        destination: map,
        animation: window.google.maps.Animation.DROP
    });
}
```

Comment: You have invalid html because of all the duplicate `id` attributes. Remove them and use class names instead

Comment: @StephenMuecke Please explain. The only "id" that was unnecessary was the one on the <ul> tag.

Comment: @Fredrik He's already explained. As soon as you put an `id` inside any kind of loop, it immediately becomes a duplicate as it will repeat `Model.RestaurantResults.Length` times. Remove all IDs within the `foreach` and replace with classes instead

Comment: For example you have multiple `<p id="lat">` elements. `document.getElementById("lat")` will only return only the first one

Comment: @StephenMuecke Alright. Should I change my `getElementById` to `getElementsByClassName` aswell then?